# Re-ask master password in pass each time

Tags: password, gpg, password-store

I just started using `pass` of by Jason A. Donenfeld as a password manager.

I entered a password (e.g. `email/username@domain.com`). To retrieve it I type

```bsh
pass email/username@domain.com
```

I'm being asked the master password. But then if I type again `pass email/username@domain.com`, the master password is not being asked and the password for `email/username@domain.com` is output in the terminal.

For security reasons, I want to be asked the master password each time I retrieve a password. How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pass` uses GnuPG to handle encryption.
Recent releases of GnuPG uses a GPG daemon.
This GPG daemon caches your valid authentication for 600 seconds (`default-cache-ttl`), which may be refreshed to another 600 seconds if you use GnuPG again within that time, up to a maximum of two hours (`max-cache-ttl`).

You have two options:

1. Kill the GPG agent process after each use of `pass`.  You do this with

   ```bsh
   gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
   ```
2. Configure the "cache max time to live" for the GPG agent (the maximum time a valid authentication is remembered, by default two hours).

   This number may be changed by changing the GPG daemon's configuration file.

   You do this by adding the following line to your `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` file (you may have to create this file):

   ```
   max-cache-ttl 0
   ```

   If a GPG agent is currently running, then make sure to terminate it with the `gpgconf` command as shown above to ensure that the agent reads the updated configuration file when it is started.

See also the `gpg-agent` manual, specifically the documentation for the `--max-cache-ttl` option (which corresponds to the `max-cache-ttl` configuration setting).  The manual also mentions the `gpgpconf --kill gpg-agent` command.

Comment: @many thanks for your answer @Kusalananda. I prefer to use the second option as the first require an active command after each use, which seems te me as a not optimized (as I might forget to do it). Regarding the second option: I'm on MacOS 11.2.3, I created `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` in which I added the line `max-cache-ttl 0`. I also did `source ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` but got `.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf:1: command not found: max-cache-ttl zsh: command not found: i`. Do you have an idea what I should do to use the second option?

Comment: @ecjb You don't source this file. The GPG agent will read it when it starts.  If you have a GPG agent currently running, then kill it with the `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` first.